# Encoding special characters in android studio

Tags: java

I've tried to encode special characters (è,ù,ò ...) content in a "Text View", by using this code:

```
TextView titolo = new TextView(context);
            String s1;
            byte[] bytes = null;
            s1 = eventList.get(index).getTitolo();
            try {
                bytes = s1.getBytes("UTF-8");
                s1 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
                titolo.setText(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

but it failed. where did i go wrong? has someone another solution?

Comment: Why are you trying to "encode special characters"? If they are not being shown correctly, it's because you're not using the right encoding when reading the data.

Comment: thank you for your answers, but i haven't understand what would you say, what should i do?

Comment: First doing `bytes = s1.getBytes("UTF-8")` and then doing `s1 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8")` does nothing. Stop trying to program as if you are employing statements as magical incantations without understanding what you are doing, because that won't get you anywhere. Joni is right - if characters are not displayed correctly, then that means you are probably doing something wrong with character encodings at the point where you are reading the text from wherever it comes from.

Comment: thank you very much, i have probably found the solution